# Regex not matching new line with parenthesis

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this text :

```
@Heurtebise (Il ramasse son sac)
Vous regretterez de m'avoir fait du mal.

(Silence.) Vous me chassez ?

@Eurydice
Le mystère est mon ennemi. Je suis décidée à le combattre.

oui oui.
```

I want 2 matches of 2 groups, the result I want is :

```
Match 1
1.  @Heurtebise (Il ramasse son sac)
2.  Vous regretterez de m'avoir fait du mal.

    (Silence.) Vous me chassez ?

Match 2
1.  @Eurydice
2. Le mystère est mon ennemi. Je suis décidée à le combattre.

   oui oui.
```

And I can't understand why my regex : `/^(\@.+)$([^(\@|\#)]+)/` does not matches the 4th line beginning by a parenthesis. This is the result I have :

```
Match 1
1.  @Heurtebise (Il ramasse son sac)
2.  Vous regretterez de m'avoir fait du mal.

Match 2
1.  @Eurydice
2. Le mystère est mon ennemi. Je suis décidée à le combattre.

   oui oui.
```

Notice how it skips the line `(Silence.) Vous me chassez ?` in `match 1`. Can't understand why !

See the full case here : http://rubular.com/r/RR2eDc4ZBQ

Can someone help ? Thanks.

Comment: Try `^(@.+)((?:\R(?!@).*)*)$`

Comment: `[^(\@|\#)]+` avoids `@` and `#` but also avoids `(`, `|` and `)`. A character class needs no alternation and parentheses. Using `[^@#]+` makes your sample code work for me.

Comment: @Corion that's it ! @WiktorStribiżew almost it but it matches `#`. Thank you very much to both of you. Maybe you want to submit the answer so I mark it as solved ?

Comment: Your sample text has no `#`, do you mean you need `^(@.+)((?:\R(?![@#]).*)*)$`? What if your lines (that you need to match) contain `@` or `#`? `[^@#]+` won't work then. I think you want to match up to a line *starting with* `#` or `@`.

Comment: Yes @WiktorStribiżew and it looks like better than mine, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(@.+)((?:\R(?![@#]).*)*)$/
```

See the [regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/lt3xxgYaaE). It will match any line starting with `@`, and then will match all consecutive lines that do not start with `@` or `#`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `(@.+)` - Group 1: `@` and the rest of the line
- `((?:\R(?![@#]).*)*)` - Group 2: 0 or more occurrences of:

  - `\R(?![@#])` - a line break sequence not followed with `@` or `#`
  - `.*` - the rest of the line
- `$` - end of line (not needed though).

Answer (score 3):

The error is in the character class to exclude a line starting with `@` or `#`:

`[^(\@|\#)]` avoids `@` and `#` but also avoids `(`, `|` and `)`. A character class needs no alternation and parentheses. Using `[^@#]` makes your sample code work for me.